# TFS. How to set <required changes> field if value has been already set?

Tags: tfs

I have some custom field in Bug WI. I want to set it to  but even if there was not NULL value after state of WI changed.
Example: Let's say I have that config in transition:

```
<TRANSITION from="Active" to="Resolved">
   <FIELD name="Version">
      <REQUIRED />
  </FIELD>
</TRANSITION>
```

When bug change it's state from Active to Resolved first time it works (field become yellow - fill required to proceed), but after, if I change state to New, then to Active and then to Resolved, there is no request to CHANGE previous field value. I think it's need check with previous value, and if it's equal, then require from user another value. Any suggestions how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.
Created hidden field "TempVersion". In transition Resolved to New/Active I copy value of Version to TempVersion.

```
<FIELD refname="TempVersion">
   <COPY from="field" field="Version" />
</FIELD>
```

In transition Active->Resolved added :

```
<TRANSITION from="Active" to="Resolved">
   <FIELD name="Version">
    <NOTSAMEAS field="TempVersion" />
    <REQUIRED />
  </FIELD>
</TRANSITION>
```

Seems like it works!

Answer (score 0):

REQUIRED rule requires a user to specify a value for the field. Users cannot save a work item until they have assigned values to all required fields. In your scenario, as the field "Version" has been specified a value, there is no restriction.

Default work item rules can't compare values, you'll need to customize a work item control to achieve what you want. You can get start by following https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/